# Data migration from NetSuite to another storage

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

So we need to migrate our old receipts from NetSuite filecabinet to another storage ( say AWS). How to do this without using any products like Celigo's SuiteStorage ?

Comment: Well, you can write a RESTlet that retrieves the contents of a file cabinet file and uploads them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Why *not* use an off-the-shelf product? It will get you results much quicker than trying to homebrew something, and you'll be able to move on to more important tasks, which should easily recoup any financial cost for a COTS product.

If your receipts are all underneath a single folder in the File Cabinet, you can just manually download the whole folder as a zip, then manually upload it wherever you want. Could take a while depending on how large the archive is, but it's a pretty simple process.

If you're hell-bent on building something yourself, there's no SuiteScript API for creating ZIP files, but you *can* SFTP individual files using SuiteScript 2.0 and the `N/sftp` module.